# How to access parameter in next function in express

Tags: javascript, express

I want to access `fromFlight,toFlight` in next function defined but I am getting output of all req object. Can anyone help me with this? This is my code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 8080;
app.listen(port, (err) => {
 if (err) {
  console.log("connect error", err);
 }
 console.log("server is up");
});
app.use(express.json());
app.all('/',(req,res)=>{
  res.send("welcome to home");
});
app.get('/getflightReturn/:fromFlight-:toFlight',(req,res,next)=>{
 console.log(req.params);
 let fromFlight = req.params.fromFlight;
 let toFlight = req.params.toFlight ;
   next(fromFlight,toFlight);
},
 (req,res,fromFlight,toFlight)=>{
   //this is next function 
   console.log(fromFlight,toFlight); 
  //res.send(fromFlight,toFlight);
 }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add `fromFlight` and `toFlight` to the request not the next like so

```
req.fromFlight = fromFlight;
req.toFlight = toFlight;
```

then you can access it like so

```
console.log(req.fromFlight)
```